# jQuery window.location.href issue in IE, null or not an object error. Could it be google maps?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, redirect, href

I have a simple redirect in my jQuery script. You click a link, it performs an asynchronous save, then sends the user to the next page via window.location.href. This works fine in all browsers except I have an issue in IE (surprise surprise). On one page in IE, I get the following error when trying to run the script

```
E.location.protocol is null or not an object
```

What is odd, is that the script works on other pages. the only thing I can see different is that the page it breaks on contains a google map, whereas the others do not.

Also, this seems to be a problem only in later versions of jQuery (1.4+) but I have to use that for other functionality.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

The save, redirect script ( which gets its location from the 'goto' attribute in an anchor tag in the page):

```
$("#save_and_go_button").click(function(){
  showAction('Saving...');         
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",  
    url: "/admin_and_tools/async/save.php",
    data: $("#main_form").serialize(),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(results){
    if(results == 'success'){
     hideAction(); 
     //alert('The record has been saved.');
     document.location.href = $("#save_and_go_button").attr('goto');
    }else{
     alert('failed' + results);
    }
    }
  });        
 });
```

EDIT: Here is the line it does on in the jQuery code:

```
    if(E.location.protocol!=="file:")
    try{return new E.XMLHttpRequest}catch(a){}try{
return new E.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(b){}};
```

Comment: just for info, you're accessing `document.location.href` (should work anyway, just in case)

Comment: "document.location.href " is not EXACTLY the same as "window.location.href" - document... is supposed to be read only but some browsers do not honor that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I've done as a work around is to drop this from the jQuery 1.4.4 source

```
/*
 * Create the request object; Microsoft failed to properly
 * implement the XMLHttpRequest in IE7 (can't request local files),
 * so we use the ActiveXObject when it is available
 * Additionally XMLHttpRequest can be disabled in IE7/IE8 so
 * we need a fallback.
 */

if ( window.ActiveXObject ) {
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
        if ( window.location.protocol !== "file:" ) {
            try {
                return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch(xhrError) {}
        }

        try {
            return new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(activeError) {}
    };
}
```

It seems to work now. Although now it def doesn't like document.location.href at all , and only goes on window.location.href. So I don't know. This will probably crash some other part of my application.

Will keep this updated. UPDATE - so far, so good.

Comment: Allow me to follow up here. I am an idiot. What I have finally found, months after the fact, is that I had a script that I was redeclaring var location as a global, destroying the original location variable. It was in my google maps initialization script, so that's how I figured google maps was screwing things up. Thank you to JSLint for helping me find this error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
document.location.href = $("#save_and_go_button").attr('goto');
```

Use

```
window.location.href = $("#save_and_go_button").attr('goto');
```

From what I understand [`document.location` is read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.location).

> `document.location` was originally a
>   read-only property, although Gecko
>   browsers allow you to assign to it as
>   well. For cross-browser safety, use
>   `window.location` instead.

Comment: I wish I could say that worked, but I still get the same error. It dies within jQuery 1.4.4, at the following line (i will edit my question to include this): if(E.location.protocol!=="file:")try{return new E.XMLHttpRequest}catch(a){}try{return new E.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(b){}};

Answer (score 1):

Change `document.location.href`  to `window.location.href`

This is an old issue with IE that crops up sometimes :)

Comment: unfortunately, I get the same error here. It is in a line of code (added to question) in the jQuery source, that specifically deals with ActiveX content.